# How I can update the new code to my site in windows azure cloud?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, cloud-hosting

I am new windows azure user. I have gotten selected for 90 days trial account and I am able to upload my ASP.NET MVC3 application to my account. My site is also running now. After I did publish my site, I added more model, views and controller to my proramme. Now I can not find a way to update my application. I can again publish my application but update option is not there. I want to update my new code only but the package option is creating full application. How I can update the new code to my site in windows azure cloud?

[Changed spelling]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Windows Azure you can publish/update an application following ways:

1. Log into you Windows Azure account. Select you hosted server name and at the top panel you will see "Upgrade" option, when you will use this option you will be given a chance to select your CSPKG and CSCFG file from local file system or from Windows Azure storage. Once you selected new or updated CSPKG, your current running service will bee upgraded.
2. You can also use Windows Azure PowerShell Cmdlets to upgrade your current running hosted service using "Update-Deployment" command:

   2.1 http://wappowershell.codeplex.com/
3. You can other 3rd party applications created using Windows Azure Service Management API to upgrade/manage your current running hosted service.

   3.1 http://wapmmc.codeplex.com/

   3.2 http://www.cerebrata.com/Products/CloudStorageStudio/Default.aspx

Note: With Visual Studio if you again publish your application, it will delete the current running hosted service and then create the new on so for update it is not the good one.

Finally based on your question about partial update, that is not supported. Even when you make a single line change in your code the deployment will be considered a full deployment even when the action is "update/upgrade". There is no diff package deployment so evertime you update your Windows Azure application, you will use the newly created CSPKG file and upgrade your hosted application.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding partial update: If you have multiple Roles, you may choose to upgrade a single role (so that would be a partial update of the *deployment*). For a given Role, all code is redeployed. If you're running more than one instance, the update will be rolled out across groups of instances, not all instances at once.

For updates such as static content: if you move these into blob storage (a great place for css, jquery, images, etc.), then you may update this content by simply uploading new items to blob storage individually. These updates don't require any code to be rebuilt or redeployed.

If you're in dev mode (e.g. non-production), you may enable Web Deploy, which then allows very fast updates of your app to the running instance. This only works in single-instance mode, and it's great when doing frequent code+test cycles.